# How to connect real device with android in windows 10

Tags: android-studio, tcp, ip, adb, device

When I connect the real device to the android studio in windows 10 then get an error with 10060 error code.

I follow step this step

1. I goto my SDK path in a **terminal**.
2. enter command **adb tcpip 5555**
3. **adb connect XXX.XXX.X.XXX:5555**

**this error gets after step 3.**

```
cannot connect to **XXX.XXX.X.XXX:XXXX**(IP ADDRESS) A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond. (10060)
```

Comment: did you set the port of the tcp first?

Comment: Edit my question...

Comment: Are your device connected to the local internet via the PC/Laptop's hotspot? If so, can you ping the device's IP and get a proper response?